# Chaning date to datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have2 columns both columns have a date but no year.

I cant just do a convert becuase part of the date is missing the year is missing
if I try:
pd.to_datetime(df13["Date"])

I get error:
Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 1-04-16 00:00:00

Sample

---

- date1  +---------+      date2
- Apr 16 +----------+    Apr 15 4:30PM
- Mar 17 +----------+    Mar 14 3:35PM
- Feb 7  +----------+    Feb 3 2:03PM
- Dec 21 +----------+    Dec 19 3:21PM

---

I like to make it a datetime column with a year and if the new date is greater than today then subtract a year. The data in the list goes as far back as a year if it just adds 2020 as the year it may be wrong in some cases

Comment: 1. Are you working with pandas? 2. Is `date1` column a string? 3. Where are the times coming from? you only described the logic for adding the year

Comment: yes pandas 3.7.1... excuse the bad columns date1 is a column and date2 is a separate column. Both are of type object. I am trying to convert each column and the result should be separate columns Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I got part of my by answer date1:
df13["Date"] = df13["Date"]+ ' 2020'
df13["Date"] = df13["Date"].apply(lambda *: datetime.strptime(*,"%b %d %Y"))

date2:
df13["SEC Form 4"].apply(lambda *: datetime.strptime(*,"%b %d %I:%M %p"))

I still have a year problem but need to add more logic